# INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.getAllVoiceShortcuts does not return anything in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11, sirishortcuts

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. But in this method

```
 INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.getAllVoiceShortcuts { (vShortCuts, error) in
        print(vShortCuts)

    }
```

vShortCuts is an empty array.

```
var suggestions = [INShortcut]()
let userActivity = NSUserActivity.init(activityType: "com.riyaz.testactivity")
userActivity.title = "test activity"
let shortCut =  INShortcut.init(userActivity: userActivity)
suggestions.append(shortCut)

INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.setShortcutSuggestions(suggestions)
```

I donated a suggestion
Opened "Shortcuts app".
Navigated to Gallery and Added the suggestion to Siri with a text.

However, 
The same text does not trigger the `appdelegate's` `willContinueUserActivity`

And also `INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.getAllVoiceShortcuts` returns an empty array.

Any help appriciated.

Comment: Same happens for us. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: beta 5, still does not work

Comment: Do you have the same problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57410172/siri-shortcuts-ios-13-bug-inuiaddvoiceshortcutbutton

Comment: Same happens for me, do you have any idea or solution?