# Siri shortcuts iOS 13 bug INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton

Tags: ios, swift, siri, ios13, sirishortcuts

In my project I use siri shortcuts with `INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton`.

I use this method to create the button and associate the `NSUserActivity`:

```
 let button = INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton(style: .blackOutline)  
 view.addSubview(button)  
 button.shortcut = INShortcut.userActivity(activityPreCreated)
```

In iOS 12 all works right, the button add or edit the shortcuts. But in iOS 13 the button only add but doesn't edit the shortcut and remain with the text "Add to Siri".

Is a bug of the beta or I do something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884855/invoiceshortcutcenter-shared-getallvoiceshortcuts-does-not-return-anything-in-io

Comment: still not working in iOS 13.3

Comment: are you trying to invoke the app from your intent handling class?